# Profiling application with VisualVM

Tags: java, profiling, visualvm

Imagine you have command-line application that takes input file and does something with it. Now imagine you want to sample/profile this application. If it were Visual Studio you would just select profiling method (sampling/instrumentation) and VS would run application for you and collect data while program completes. But as far as I can see there is no similar functionality in VisualVM. You have to run your application, then select it in VisualVM and then explicitly start sampling/profiling. The problem is that sometimes execution of program with certain input data takes less time than it is required to setup VisualVM. Also with such an approach there is no possibility to batch profile application. Someone has suggested to start application in debug mode from Eclipse and set breakpoint somewhere in the beginning of main() method. Then setup VisualVM and continue execution. But I have suspicion that running in Debug vs Release mode has performance implications on its own.
Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new [Startup Profiler plugin](https://visualvm.github.io/startupprofiler.html) for VisualVM 1.3.6, which allows you to profile your application from its startup. See this [article](http://java.dzone.com/announcements/startup-profiler-plugin) for additional information.

Answer (score 1):

If the program does I/O, the Visual Studio sampler will not see the I/O because it is a "CPU Sampler" (even if nearly all of the time is spent waiting for I/O).

If you use Instrumentation, you won't see any line-level information because it only summarizes at the function level.

I use [*this technique*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771).

If the program runs too quickly to sample, just put a temporary outer loop around it of, say, 100 or 1000 iterations.

The difference between Debug and Release mode will be next to nothing unless you are spending a good fraction of time in tight loops, *in your code*, where the loops do not contain any function calls, OR if you are doing data structure operations that do a lot of validation in the libraries.

If you are, then your samples will show that you are, and you will know that Release will make a speed difference.

As far as batch profiling is concerned, I don't. I just keep an eye on the program's overall throughput rate. If there is some input that seems to make it take too long, then I do the sampling procedure on the program with that input, see what the problem is, and fix it.